# Images not displaying in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, image

So for some reason my images are just showing a broken image icon when I open my website from the adminpanel in WP. But when I open the index.php file the images are showing just as I want them to. Same with my javascript.

I have linked the image directory correctly since they are showing up when I only open the index.php file. They are also in the media library in wordpress.

Maybe a simpler explanation is: 
localhost/website/wordpress = ***no images, only broken image icons.*** 
localhost/website/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mywebsite/index.php = ***the images are showing.***

**EDIT:** I found out you could copy the link that wordpress gives you for every image, and that made it work. 
Is that the only way of doing it or is there another way?

Comment: Probably something is wrong with your file path, but we need more info in order to help you. Go to console and inform us about the errors

Answer (score 0):

Check is your .htaccess file for rules applied to images or image folder. Rename  it to be sure
Remove image related wordpress plugins like "Adaptive Images"

Answer (score 0):

It may due to file accessibility permission issue. Just give permission to your image folder. check your .htaccess file (on root).
Install a file browsing plugin or directly go to the hosted site and edit the .htaccess file. Add the folder name on the file

Comment: What function am I looking for when I change permissions in the htaccess file?